# How to remove square label from tooltip and make its information in one line?

Tags: chart.js

How can I remove this square from tooltip?

[image]

I would prefer if I could manage to just have it one line like this: February - 2

```
var data = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
        datasets: [
        {
            data: [1,2,3]
        }
        ]
    };

    var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

here you go:

> jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1v9fy5mz/

code:

html

`<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>`

js:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
      custom: function(tooltip) {
        if (!tooltip) return;
        // disable displaying the color box;
        tooltip.displayColors = false;
      },
      callbacks: {
        // use label callback to return the desired label
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return tooltipItem.xLabel + " :" + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        },
        // remove title
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why do I get more padding on top if I just change the font to Open Sans and how to even this out? http://jsfiddle.net/xppkLg59/

Comment: seems like it has to do with the title having soem spacing that cannot be removed. move the text to `title` and make `label` return null. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t60cd3bg/

Comment: the other way you can do it, is change the `tooltip.yPadding =3;` here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v45sydkv/

Answer (score 88):

Add this in your `options` object

```
tooltips: {
  displayColors: false
}
```

**Update for version 3 or greater** (from @hanumanDev below):

Remove 's' from tooltips

```
tooltip: {
  displayColors: false
}
```

Comment: This solution is minimal and works perfect, but if you use accepted solution it will just remove the color box but there will be space after label.

Comment: The accepted answer gives a lengthy code and does not even explain how it works. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Easiest and fastest

Comment: update: for version 3 they've changed it to 'tooltip' instead of 'tooltips'

Comment: In version 3.8.0 the 'tooltip' config should live in 'plugins' too. E.g. options.plugins.tooltip.displayColors = false;

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can anyone take a look? Line 116 https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 6):

```
tooltips: {
      displayColors: false,
      callbacks: {
        // use label callback to return the desired label
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return tooltipItem.xLabel + " :" + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        },
        // remove title
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return;

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 3.8.0 of the chart.js plugin the tooltip config needs to go in the plugins config object, like this:

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      displayColors: false
    }
  }
}
```