# Hiding tooltip color box in Chart.js not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

As per Chart.js docs, all that's needed to remove the color box from tooltips is to add `displayColors: false` to `tooltip`, that's also the accepted answer to a similar question here [How to remove square label from tooltip and make its information in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793622/how-to-remove-square-label-from-tooltip-and-make-its-information-in-one-line)
But it doesn't work in my code. Here's the link to the editor https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: `displayColors: false` should be under `options.plugins.tooltip`, you have put it under `data.datasets[].tooltip`.

Comment: @kikon I have updated the code but it's still not working, can you please take a look? I added ```options``` to data as well as directly onto the ```Line``` component using the ```options``` props. Line 133 https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntdk3g?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```jsx
<LineChart chartData={activityData} options={{ 
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        displayColors: false // tried this also
      }
    }
}}/>
```

is working OK, if you enable the `options` argument in LineChart.js ([stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nxq73c?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FLineChart.js))

However, the attempt to set `options` at the same level as `labels` and `datasets` will not work, since `labels` and `datasets` are keys of `data`, and `options` should not be part of `data`, but at the same level as `data`; in react-charts2 this means `options` should be a separate argument to the `Line` (or other) component, see this [doc link](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/components/line).